# Unable to download Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm not familiar with Spring eco and  to run gradle to install required modules.

I just cloned this spring boot repo and tried to run it

> git@github.com:didinj/springboot-mongodb-security.git

```
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.7.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    at .....
```

How come? Does this mean the 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE' is not in this world anymore? If so, the package management system is holly crap.

What should I do? I cloned bunch of git repos from the github and try to run gradle and always have this problem.

Java ecosystem is too broken. Unlike NPM or ruby gem which is so stable and no-brain to use.

Is there related to my gradle setting, java version, or anything else?

Comment: Cloning the repo works and building it works fine for me

Comment: Version 2.1.7.RELEASE isn't referenced anywhere in that repository (it uses 2.0.2.RELEASE), so you must have tried to change the version yourself or you are mixing up which Git repository you are building from. If you tried to change it yourself, how did you do it?

Comment: "... Unlike NPM ..." Are you serious?!?

Comment: NPM is not good as Ruby bundle... but sill better than Java way. Finally, the root cause was Java version. What a useless error message on the console. But thanks for these folks for giving me the hint

Answer (score 1):

Use JDK 8. Change or config MongoDB at https://github.com/didinj/springboot-mongodb-security/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties

```
git clone https://github.com/didinj/springboot-mongodb-security.git
cd springboot-mongodb-security
gradlew bootRun
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `2.1.7.RELEASE` version of this plugin available at Maven Central Repository (which is used in your `build.gradle` script), since this version is outdated. But it's still accessible at Gradle Plugin Repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.1.17.RELEASE).

So you should either use least available plugin version from Central repository (2.2.0.RELEASE) or add Gradle Plugin Repository to the `repositories` section of  your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()

  maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}
```

Comment: The version is still available in both [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.1.7.RELEASE/pom) and the [Gradle Plugin repository](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot/2.1.7.RELEASE). While probably better to use newer versions, it is still possible to run with older versions. They  are not removed from either repository (you can even go back to version 1.0.0 from 2014).

Comment: @BjørnVester I may be wrong but I don't see 2.1.7 at Maven Central (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin?repo=central).

Comment: When you use the `plugins` DSL block, there need to be a marker artifact on the Gradle Plugin repository. For Spring Boot, this is named `org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin` and it is the one you have linked to. But on MvnRepository, you have to select the Gradle Plugins tab to see which artifacts are available on this particular repository. I don't know why they _also_ have newer versions on central though. The marker artifact then points to the actual plugin with name `spring-boot-gradle-plugin`, which is on central.